# parsing log file using java Grok api not working but working in Grok online debugger

Tags: java, json, parsing, grok, logparser

Hi I have a problem when parsing a log file using code and grok api downloaded from Github (I'm not using logstash) when I test using Grok debugger https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ 
it works fine but in my code it won't

here is a log line from the file I want to parse :

> DEBUG 2015-06-17 14:44:57,475 (com.test.logging.exceptionmanager.ExceptionTreeModel:findNodeByIdRecursively:651) - Could not find node with Id: 1913

and this is my code :

```
public class LogParse {

public static void main(String[] args) throws GrokException {


        // Get an instance of grok
        Grok grok = new Grok();

        // add a pattern to grok
        grok.addPattern("LOGLEVEL", "\\w+");
        grok.addPattern("YEAR", "\\w+");
        grok.addPattern("MONTHNUM", "\\w+");
        grok.addPattern("MONTHDAY", "\\w+");
        grok.addPattern("HOUR", "\\w+");
        grok.addPattern("MINUTE", "\\w+");
        grok.addPattern("SECOND", "\\w+");
        grok.addPattern("GREEDYDATA", "\\w+");



     grok.compile("%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} %{YEAR:year}-%{MONTHNUM:month}-%{MONTHDAY:day} %{HOUR:hour}:%{MINUTE:minute}:%{SECOND:second} %{GREEDYDATA:data}");


        try{
               FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("C://file.log");
               BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
               String log;
                //output
                BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("out.json"));

               /* read log line by line */
               while ((log = br.readLine()) != null)   {

                 System.out.println (log);
                 Match gm = grok.match(log);
                    gm.captures();

                    //output
                    System.out.println(gm.toJson());
                    output.write(gm.toJson());
                    output.newLine();

               }
               output.close();
               fstream.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                 System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }       }}
```

thanks for your help.

Comment: I updated my code now it works fine , it was a problem in the regex expressions

Comment: I've rollbacked your changes: please find [your solution in the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/b62baf51-c073-44e5-b428-9eb5dbebb0e9/view-source) and post it as an answer of its own instead, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The working code :

```
 public class LogParse {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws GrokException, IOException {


        // Get an instance of grok
        Grok grok = new Grok();

        // add a pattern to grok
        grok.addPattern("LOGLEVEL", "\\w+");
        grok.addPattern("YEAR", "\\w+");
        grok.addPattern("MONTHNUM", "((?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2]))");
        grok.addPattern("MONTHDAY", "(?:[+-]?(?:[0-9]+))");
        grok.addPattern("HOUR", "(?:[+-]?(?:[0-9]+))");
        grok.addPattern("MINUTE", "(?:[+-]?(?:[0-9]+))");
        grok.addPattern("SECOND", "(?:(?:[0-5][0-9]|60)(?:[:.,][0-9]+)?)");
        grok.addPattern("GREEDYDATA", ".*");


        grok.compile("%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} %{YEAR:year}-%{MONTHNUM:month}-%{MONTHDAY:day} %{HOUR:hour}:%{MINUTE:minute}:%{SECOND:second} (%{GREEDYDATA:data}) - %{GREEDYDATA:message} %{GREEDYDATA:Erreur}");
        grok.compile("%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} %{YEAR:year}-%{MONTHNUM:month}-%{MONTHDAY:day} %{HOUR:hour}:%{MINUTE:minute}:%{SECOND:second} (%{GREEDYDATA:data}) - %{GREEDYDATA:message}");


        try{

               FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("C://file.log");
               BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
               String log;
                //output
                BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("out.json"));

               /* read log line by line */
               while ((log = br.readLine()) != null)   {

                 System.out.println (log);
                 Match gm = grok.match(log);
                    gm.captures();

                    //output
                    System.out.println(gm.toJson());
                    output.write(gm.toJson());
                    output.newLine();

               }
               output.close();
               fstream.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                 System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }   }}
```

Comment: I changed regular expressions in addPattern functions to make it work.

Comment: You should describe that in your answer a bit more detailed, so that others can understand it and learn from you.